# combile asp.net aspx pages with asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two separate projects. One is my web application that has written in ASP.NET MVC. The other one is an ASP.NET application with .aspx pages that is a blog for my web application. Currently I use a subdomain for blog and web application itself is running on main domain. But for SEO purposes I want my blog to run on a route like maindomain.com/blog. To achieve this I want to add a new route in my mvc project named /blog and when a user navigate to this route could visit the blog. What is the best practice to do this? Consider that the code base of these two projects are rather big and have two separate connection strings and I prefer not to merge them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create new web application called "blog" (and configure it to your Web Forms app) inside your MVC app:

[image]

1. Open IIS manager (inetmgr)
2. Right click on your MVC app -> "Add Application"
3. Configure new app (set the name "blog" and route to your blog app).

Comment: Could you plz add more info to your answer? How exactly can I add a new project into my mvc app? Where your attached image refer to? How can I configure my route to start web forms app?

Comment: @MohamadGhafourian You don't need to add your project into MVC app. You just need to add new web application on IIS (inetmgr) (see the screenshot) and that app have to point to the your blog app.